# How do I add secondary axis to highstock charts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I'm still pretty wet behind the ears when it comes to javascript. I need some help adding a secondary axis that is something like revenue to a highstock chart that also uses $.getJSON (JSONP) to snag a json file to populate the data.

Check out the JSFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tnwwfd2j/). And here is the sample data set to play [with](http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=msft-c.json&callback=?). And finally, an example of [secondary axis](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-dual-axes/) in Highcharts.

```
$(function () {
    var seriesOptions = [],
        seriesCounter = 0,
        names = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'GOOG'],
        // create the chart when all data is loaded
        createChart = function () {

            $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

                rangeSelector: {
                    selected: 4
                },

                yAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value + '%';
                        }
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 2,
                        color: 'silver'
                    }]
                },

                yAxis: {
                floor: 0
            },

                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        compare: 'value'
                    }
                },

                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
                    valueDecimals: 2
                },

                series: seriesOptions
            });
        };

    $.each(names, function (i, name) {

        $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=' + name.toLowerCase() + '-c.json&callback=?',    function (data) {

            seriesOptions[i] = {
                name: name,
                data: data
            };

            // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
            // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
            seriesCounter += 1;

            if (seriesCounter === names.length) {
                createChart();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Any help and explanations (so I can learn) is much appreciated. I'm still trying to learn how to tie jsonp and charting together, especially multiple series of data and json files.

Comment: Secondary Y-axis? if so, you just need to use an array. for example: `yAxis:[{..axis1 properties..},{..axis 2 properties..}]`. Just note that as long as no series attached to the axis, it will not show labels. just add the property "yAxis:n", to your series, where `n` is the axis key (first one is 0, second is 1...)

Comment: So, I would need to add a new axis label and series attached to that label ideally. I did try to add a new label before, but no series attached so nothing showed. I guess that's why.

Comment: As @MorKadosh said you need to have an array of axis objects, then in the series object, refer to particualr yAxis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it like this:

```
yAxis: [{
    labels: { ... },
    title: { ... },
    ...
},
{
    labels: { ... },
    title: { ... },
    ...
}]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5eem7a2a/1/

Comment: Thank you, Raein Hashemi.  This is exactly what I need.  By the way, I edited your example to show the time on x-axis.  
http://jsfiddle.net/pw8v93hj/